# Dual Monitors on Crunch Bang

Tags: crunchbang

I'm running Crunch Bang and want to add a second monitor.  When I plug the second monitor into my laptop, nothing happens.  I can't find anything in the "Super+Space" menu that has to do with display settings.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Super+Space then System then Display settings
see http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=19797 for more help